Kramers-kronig relations with an addtional constant
Suppose I have a complex function $\chi(\omega)$, using Kramers-Kronig relations, we have:
$$
\chi_1(\omega) = \frac{1}{\pi}\mathcal{P}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\chi_2(\omega')}{\omega'-\omega}d\omega'
$$
However, suppose I have another function, which is $\varepsilon(\omega)=\chi(\omega)+1$, using the Kramers-Kronig relations on $\varepsilon(\omega)$, we have:
$$
\varepsilon_1(\omega) = \frac{1}{\pi}\mathcal{P}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\varepsilon_2(\omega')}{\omega'-\omega}d\omega'
$$,
which means that:
$$
\chi_1(\omega) = \frac{1}{\pi}\mathcal{P}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\chi_2(\omega')}{\omega'-\omega}d\omega' -1
$$
and the contradiction raises.
Why the contradiction, can anyone explain to me?

A condition for the Kramers-Kronig relations is that $|\chi(\omega)|\to 0$ as $|\omega|\to\infty$. But in that case $|\varepsilon (\omega)|\to 1$ in this same limit, so $\varepsilon(\omega)$ need not obey the Kramer-Kronig relations as such. Indeed, the validity of the Kramers-Kronig relations for $\chi(\omega)$ instead yields
$$\varepsilon_1(\omega) = 1+\frac{1}{\pi}\mathcal{P}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\varepsilon_2(\omega')}{\omega'-\omega}d\omega'$$
as the appropriate equivalent to Kramers-Kronig for $\varepsilon(\omega)$.

You clear my doubts, thanks for the nice answer!
